# mongoengine unique constraing

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, model, mongoengine

i have this model:

```
class SourceModel(Document):
    name = StringField(
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=50,
        required=True,
    )
    # some fields
```

when i try to run this code:

```
for source in SOURCES:
    SourceModel(**source).save()
```

i have this error:

```
mongoengine.errors.NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: mirad.source_model.$name_1  dup key: { : null })
```

i don't know why this error occured becuase i havn't `unique` field in my model. i change this code to :

```
for source in SOURCES:

    try:
        SourceModel(**source).save()
    except NotUniqueError:
         old_source = SourceModel.objects(name=source['name']).first()
         print old_source  # this line print None
```

why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not have a unique index defined in your Document model.  But at some point in time a unique index was created for "name".

So you need to drop that index in mongodb, you can do so in the shell like so:

```
 db = new Mongo().getDB("mirad");
 db.source_model.dropIndex("name_1")
```